# export * as name from

Tags: javascript, typescript

MDN seems to be listing `export * as name from ''` as 'Aggregating modules': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export. However this does not work: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/djwqe.png]

I did not find an open issue about it on MDN nor on typescript. So is it part of the standard?

As a workaround instead of `export * as name from './file'` i have been doing:

```
import * as name from './file'
export { name }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export * as ns from` will be available in [TS 3.8](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34898) ([issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4813)).

You can find the corresponding JS proposal [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-ns-from).

Answer (score 2):

The `export * as name` syntax is only supported as of [TypeScript 3.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export-all-as-x).